# How do we add footnotes with different symbols in the same sentences?

Tags: pdftex, footnotes

For instance, I would like to realise different footnote symbols with this code:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.`**`\footnote{This is the first footnote.}`** `Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.`**`\footnote[Roman]{This is the another first footnote.}`** `Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.`**`\footnote{the second footnote.}`**

And these footnotes:

> 1 This is the first footnote.
> i This is the another first footnote.
> 2 the second footnote.

I have already scrutinised `footmisc` and `\renewcommand`, but unfortunately this didn't work as I wished. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would *not* suggest the syntax you used, since the standard LaTeX `\footnote` already takes an optional argument (a replacement footnote number).

Personally I think it would be clearer if the footnotes appear with "like" footnotes grouped together; that is, all Arabic numeral numbered footnotes appear first, followed by all roman numeral numbered ones. If you are happy with the style suggested in the previous sentence, then you can just use `manyfoot`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % Just so that the demo output has less useless whitespace

\usepackage{manyfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{R}[roman]

\begin{document}
Test\footnote[14]{Should be 14}. Test\footnote{Should be 1}. Test\footnoteR{Should be i}. Test\footnoteR[15]{Should be xv}. Test\footnote{Should be 2}. Test\footnoteR{Should be ii}.
\end{document}
```

Note that `manyfoot` has a different syntax than what you suggest. But this is probably the option with the least work required, and probably has code that is better tested.

---

Now, `manyfoot` by design prints the different footnote series separately; the way it is designed is incompatible with having the footnote series mingle. If you want the series mixed, the following is a streamlined version of [another previously given answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709804/119).

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % Just so that the demo output has less useless whitespace


\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\DeclareFootnoteOption[2]{
        \newcounter{footnote#1}
        \expandafter\def\csname footnote#1\endcsname{%
                \def\@mpfn{footnote#1}%
                \def\thempfn{\csname#2\endcsname{footnote#1}}%
                \oldfootnote}
}
\makeatother
\DeclareFootnoteOption{A}{arabic}
\DeclareFootnoteOption{R}{roman}
\def\footnote{\footnoteA}  % So that \footnote becomes a shorthand for \footnoteA


\begin{document}
Test\footnote[14]{Should be 14}. Test\footnote{Should be 1}. Test\footnoteR{Should be i}. Test\footnoteR[15]{Should be xv}. Test\footnote{Should be 2}. Test\footnoteR{Should be ii}.
\end{document}
```

Here we used the fact that the default definition of `\footnote` in `latex.ltx` has built-in flexibility to use other counters and other formatting of the footnotemark.

---

Finally, if you prefer the syntax where the formatting option is passed as an optional argument to `\footnote`, consider the following, which is defined using `\NewDocumentCommand` to make use of `()` as the delimiter for the formatting argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % Just so that the demo output has less useless whitespace


\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\DeclareFootnoteOption[2]{
        \newcounter{footnote#1}
        \expandafter\def\csname footnote#1\endcsname{%
                \def\@mpfn{footnote#1}%
                \def\thempfn{\csname#2\endcsname{footnote#1}}%
                \oldfootnote}
}
\makeatother
\DeclareFootnoteOption{arabic}{arabic}
\DeclareFootnoteOption{roman}{roman}
\RenewDocumentCommand\footnote{D(){arabic}}{\csname footnote#1\endcsname}


\begin{document}
Test\footnote[14]{Should be 14}. Test\footnote{Should be 1}. Test\footnote(roman){Should be i}. Test\footnote(roman)[15]{Should be xv}. Test\footnote{Should be 2}. Test\footnote(roman){Should be ii}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather crude solution I made with a command called `\specialfootnote`, which sets different counters for each counter style among `roman`, `Roman`, `alph`, and `Alph`. In the example below, the lowercase `roman` footnotes and the normal Arabic numeral footnotes are numbered independently from each other.

[image: The seven footnotes produced by the code below. The roman numeral footnotes are completely independent from the Indo-Arabic numeral footnotes, resulting in footnotes numbered as 1, i, ii, 2, 3, 4 iii.]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{footnoteroman}\setcounter{footnoteroman}{0}
\newcounter{footnoteRoman}\setcounter{footnoteRoman}{0}
\newcounter{footnotealph} \setcounter{footnotealph}{0}
\newcounter{footnoteAlph} \setcounter{footnoteAlph}{0}

\def\specialfootnote[#1]#2{%
  {%
    \setcounter{footnote}{\value{footnote#1}}%
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\csname#1\endcsname{footnote}}\footnote{#2}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  }%
  \stepcounter{footnote#1}%
}

\begin{document}

I am number one.\footnote{This is the first footnote.}

I am also number one.\specialfootnote[roman]{This is the another first footnote.}

I am number two.\specialfootnote[roman]{The second footnote.}

I am number two, too.\footnote{The second footnote, part two.}

I am number three.\footnote{Third footnote.}

I am number four.\footnote{Fourth footnote}

I am still three.\specialfootnote[roman]{Third footnote, again.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In LaTeX, `\specialfootnote[#1]#2` would imply that `[#1]` is optional.  But the way you've defined it, it's required or else you'll get a strange error message.  It would be better to use `\newcommand` or `\NewDocumentCommand` to make it truly optional, or make it required.

Comment: See also `\@fnsymbol` (source2e.pdf page 469).

Comment: @JohnKormylo: did you mean to point the OP to looking at `\thempfn` and `\@mpfn`? // -At- gz839918: Internally `\footnote` doesn't "operate" on the `footnote` counter or use `\thefootnote`; instead, it operates on the counter whose name is the replacement text for `\@mpfn` and it formats it using the macro `\thempfn`. So instead of copying the value of `footnoteroman` into `footnote`, you can just set `\@mpfn` to `footnoteroman` and cut out the middleman. See the second solution in my answer.

Comment: @WillieWong I appreciate the insight into how `\footnote` works internally! +1 to your answer